# Setinterval slide image

Tags: javascript

This is what I've done :

```
<img id="neigeuint2"  border="0" />
var image=document.getElementById("neigeuint2");
var img_array = [
    "http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000000/fff.jpg&text=+",
    "http://dummyimage.com/300x200/F00/F00.jpg&text=+"
];
var index = 0;
function slide() {
    index = index % img_array.length;
    image.src = img_array[index];
    index++;
}
setInterval(slide, 800);
```

It works, but I want to copy paste and rename `neigeuint2` to have two animations at the same time.

But when I do that, just one of them work, How I can get this to work?

Comment: Can you show the complete code? The one if not working.

Answer (score 0):

[There you go](http://jsfiddle.net/nullpotent/bm4eL/1/)

```
var image1=document.getElementById("neigeuint2");
var image2=document.getElementById("neigeuint3");

var img_array = [
    "http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000000/fff.jpg&text=+",
    "http://dummyimage.com/300x200/F00/F00.jpg&text=+"
];

function slide(index, image) {
    index = index % img_array.length;
    image.src = img_array[index];
}
var index1 = 0; 
setInterval(function() { slide(index1++, image1) }, 800);
var index2 = 0; 
setInterval(function() { slide(index2++, image2) }, 800);
```

[But I wouldn't do it the way you did...](http://jsfiddle.net/nullpotent/bm4eL/2/)

Comment: Not a problem. I thought about explaining why your code doesn't work the way you expect it to; but there are tons of same answers here, I just don't feel like it. 
The keyword here is: scoping. Learn your language, it's all I have to say.